# Cannot get legends to display in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am novice in R (I use RStudio) and ggplot2.  I cannot get a legend to display on any plot.  I wonder if that means I have some global parameter set that forbids legends?? I have looked through this site and others and have tried too many things to list, to no avail.  Here is sample working code.  I need a legend that describes the two lines (green and red).  What do I need to do?
Thank you.

---

```
ndata <- 100


library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
require(ggplot2)
require("ggplot2")
require(car)
library(grid)
library(mgcv)
library(Matrix)
require(graphics)
options(error = browser)



legend_test <- function (ndata)  {

  #Generate the predictor values, which are times in the sequence.
  xmin <- -5
  xmax <- 5
  x <- runif(ndata, min = xmin, max = xmax)

  #Sort into increasing order
  x <- sort(x)

  #Define the mean values to lie along a straight line
  int <- 1
  slp <- 1
  st_lne <- as.vector(int + slp*x)

  #Generate normal random deviates as measurements errors
  #along the straight line
  zq <- rnorm(ndata, mean = st_lne, sd = 1)

  #Plot the measurements and the fits
  xq <- data.frame(x, zq)
  ggp <- ggplot(data = xq, aes(x, zq)) + geom_point(shape = 16, size = 2)  

  ggp <- ggp + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=25))
  ggp <- ggp + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=25))
  ggp <- ggp + theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=25))
  ggp <- ggp + theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=25))

  ymin <- int + slp*xmin - 2
  ymax <- int + slp*xmax + 2
  ggp <- ggp + xlab("x") + ylab("y")  + xlim(xmin, xmax) + ylim(ymin, ymax)

  #Add the theoretical line
  x_regress <- as.double(c(xmin, xmax))
  y_int <- as.double(int)
  y_slp <- as.double(slp)
  y_regress <- c(y_int + y_slp*x_regress[1], y_int + y_slp*x_regress[2])
  lmodf <- data.frame(x_regress, y_regress)
  ggp <- ggp + geom_path(data = lmodf, aes(x_regress, y_regress), linetype = 1, size = 0.7, color = "green")

  #Simple Regression fit to straight line

  lmo <- lm(zq ~ x)
  #Add the regression line
  y_int <- as.double(lmo$coefficients[1])
  y_slp <- as.double(lmo$coefficients[2])
  y_regress <- c(y_int + y_slp*x_regress[1], y_int + y_slp*x_regress[2])
  lmodf <- data.frame(x_regress, y_regress)
  ggp <- ggp + geom_path(data = lmodf, aes(x_regress, y_regress), linetype = 2, size = 0.9, color = "red")

    print(ggp)


}
```

Comment: Give the annotate function a try. `ggp + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = "Is this what you want?",color='green')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Add the theoretical line
  y_int <- as.double(int)
  y_slp <- as.double(slp)
  lmodf <- data.frame(Guide ='Theory',Slope = y_slp, Intercept = y_int)

  #Simple Regression fit to straight line

  lmo <- lm(zq ~ x)
  #Add the regression line
  y_int <- as.double(lmo$coefficients[1])
  y_slp <- as.double(lmo$coefficients[2])
  lmodf <- rbind(lmodf,data.frame(Guide='Reality',Slope = y_slp, Intercept = y_int))
  ggp <- ggp + 
    geom_abline(data = lmodf, aes(slope = Slope, intercept = Intercept,color =Guide,linetype = Guide), size = 0.9)+
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')

    print(ggp)
```

I tried to modify your code as little as possible to get it to work, so this is a little awkward, but it gets you down the right path.

Also, note that you can set all the axis text size values with one call to theme.

`ggp <- ggp + 
  theme(
    axis.text=element_text(size=25), 
    axis.title=element_text(size=25)
  )`

You only need to use `axis.text.y` when you wish to adjust `y` separately from `x`.

Comment: Works great.  Hadley Wickham's ggplot2 book says legends are "automatic."  But not for me.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @GeorgeYost They are automatic. The code I gave you uses the automatic legend generating in ggplot. The trick is that I assigned `color=Guide` in the `aes()`. That way ggplot knows what thing I want sorted by color. Then it generates the legend for me.